# Logging bind values for a stored procedure using JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

At debug logging level, JOOQ is logging stored proc statement, execution time and number of results. But it is not logging the actual bind values for the stored procedure. I am using JOOQ with Oracle. 
The Settings object is prepared as following -

```
Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
    .set(new JooqTxConnectionProvider(dataSource))
    .set(SQLDialect.ORACLE)
    .set(recordMapperProvider)
    .set(new Settings()
        .withRenderSchema(false)
        .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS)
        .withExecuteLogging(false))
    .set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(
             new CallableStatementExecuteListener()),
         new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(
             new LoggingExecuteTimeListener(configurationManager)));
```

The logging output appears as following -

2014-01-27 23:03:31,204 DEBUG [requests-52 R:30 A:400663505008 E:400663505008 S:400049845008]  org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Executing query          : begin STATE.CREATE_SESSION(ID_OUT => ?, SERVER => ?); end;

2014-01-27 23:03:31,207 DEBUG [requests-52 R:30 A:400663505008 E:400663505008 S:400049845008]  org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Query executed           : Total: 2.976ms

2014-01-27 23:03:31,207 DEBUG [requests-52 R:30 A:400663505008 E:400663505008 S:400049845008]  org.jooq.tools.StopWatch - Finishing                : Total: 3.186ms, +0.209ms

What I would like to see is the line containing "with bind values" and actual bind parameters to the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that jOOQ 3.2.2's default logger `LoggerListener` does not inline bind values of standalone stored procedure calls. That's a bug and should be fixed: [#2987](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2987)

Anyway, if you want bind values to be logged, you have several options:

1. Enable "trace" logging. jOOQ will then log all bind values on a new line, each. But that's pretty verbose
2. Implement your own logger that re-renders the Routine object with inline bind values. This can be done as such:

   ```
   @Override
   public void renderEnd(RenderContext ctx) {
       // [...]
       log.debug(DSL.using(configuration)
                    .renderInlined(ctx.routine()));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on Lukas's answer a bit, here's what my current configuration looks like, with jOOQ 3.1.0, including the workaround for this logging bug:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(
    new DefaultConfiguration()
        .set(new DataSourceConnectionProvider(dataSource))
        .set(SQLDialect.ORACLE)
        .set(
            new org.jooq.conf.Settings()
                .withRenderFormatted(true)
                .withExecuteLogging(false)
        )
        .set(new ExecuteListenerProvider() {
            @Override
            public ExecuteListener provide() {
                return new LoggerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void renderEnd(ExecuteContext ctx) {
                        super.renderEnd(ctx);
                        JooqLogger log =
                            JooqLogger.getLogger(LoggerListener.class);
                        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            if (ctx.routine() != null) {
                                log.debug(
                                    DSL.using(ctx.configuration())
                                        .renderInlined(ctx.routine())
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        })
);
```